# With "use strict" enabled, why can I assign a variable without let while using prompt()

Tags: javascript, use-strict

I wrote `"use strict";` at the top of my script.

I can't write `num = 5;` because I get `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: num`.

To fix this I can write `let num = 5;`.

Using that logic, why am I allowed to write `name = prompt("What is your name?");`?

Shouldn't I have to write `let name = prompt("What is your name?")`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you're running this in the browser, you're seeing this behavior because of the [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) property.  You're second example is storing the value returned by `prompt` in this property.

If window had a built-in `num` property your first example would work as well.

Of course, in actual code you'd want to create a variable to store the `prompt` value rather than clobbering `window.name`.